# Word 2007 VBA code to clear document values

Tags: vba, activex, ms-word

My company has a macro template document for users to populate a form. The template uses the AutoNew function on launch to open a User Form, the data is entered, the user clicks OK, then the data is placed onto the document at bookmarked locations and the User Form hides and unloads. This is a fairly standard operation on many of our documents.

However, the users tell me that they want to create several documents in succession (each with different data) from a particular template, without closing the form and going back to the source and launching the template again.

How would an ActiveX button on the document that relaunches the form and creates a Document 1 version work? Wouldn't an ActiveX button need to be in a protected state to function, thus preventing the original macro from populating the document?

I've written VBA code before, but I've never encountered this situation (I'm definitely a newbie). It's very likely that there's a much better solution that I'm unaware of. Can anyone help, please? Many thanks!

Comment: Solved. Instead of using an ActiveX control, I added a command button to the User Form to "Start a New Document". The User Form has ShowModal = False. The button launched a message box to alert the user that the current User Form would unload, and a new document and User Form would appear. The user can choose OK to launch a new instance of the User Form and document (based on the template), or Cancel to resume any further entries into the current User Form. The first document remains open in the background in Word so that the user can save it to their chosen location.

Comment: If anyone has another solution, I am open to modifying my solution. Thanks!